# Extracting plain text from desktop apps - for example, a Spotify playlist

Tags: spotify, text-extraction, plaintext, macos-high-sierra

Apologies if this is too high-level.

Looking to extract the Track/Artist information from a Spotify playlist into simple plain text. Simply to have a clipboard-friendly tracklist.

Working in the current OSX desktop Spotify app. Was looking for pointers on where to start, or if there’s a simple way of going about it.

Comment: You could try the Spotify API https://developer.spotify.com/ to do this, although will be a bit of work it is possible, or try finding an application that does this already

Comment: thanks the API is a good idea